# when to run or start a docker container

Tags: docker, containers, restart, conventions

As far as I understood, 'docker create' creates a new container from an image, 'docker start' starts the container (conditions apply so the container doesn't stop again immediately) and 'docker run' does both (with some differences in the details, but let's ignore them for now).

What I don't understand is when to use which. Let me explain:

For a normal executable, I run it by starting a new process. When the process dies, it is gone, and I start the executable again by creating a new process. There is no other way.

Some executables become daemons and keep running, so now there are three ways: Interact with a running daemon, start a second one, or stop and restart. With very few exceptions, running a second instance of the daemon is not useful, and you'd usually interact with the running instance, restarting it only when it locks up or to change its configuration. So again, it is clear to me how to use such a program.

For docker applications, things are not as clear to me. Of course, we have daemons and non-daemons there too, but for both of them, it is not clear to me whether I should use them by creating a new container or restarting an existing container. For daemons, there is the added distinction of starting a non-running daemon and restarting a running daemon, each of which can be done with the existing or a new container. On top of that, there is a third class of applications besides fire-and-forget and daemons, namely VM-like containers that just have a file system and a shell, and contain multiple programs to run.

As far as my knowledge goes, all this is especially relevant when the application stores run-time data on a file system that is private to the container, so creating a second container would create a second file system independent of the first one (with important files possibly spread across those file systems).

Of those docker-based applications I have used, none seems to have described this in its manual, so it seems that there are best practices on when to create or re-use containers, but then I could not find anything about that on the internet either. I could only find sites that explain the mechanics of those commands, but no best practices.

When should I create a new container, and when should I restart an existing one? If "it depends", how do you find out?

Comment: Start using docker-compose. No need to use lower level docker commands.

Comment: You typically use an existing container as long as there's no reason to create a new one. E.g. you have a new image version.

Comment: I’m using Docker for 2 years now. I’ve never used docker create in my life.

Comment: The question is about creating versus re-using, not about docker create as a specific means to do that. The question equally applies to docker start vs. docker run. Also, the point is to understand things; adding docker-compose as an additional layer won't help with that.

Comment: Christoph, if you can point me to some sources that go into detail, I'd be interested. Also WRT "docker system prune", which seems to go the other direction, namely throwaway containers.